# SharePoint Designer 2013 403 Forbidden when connecting to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

All.

I have a new laptop to which I downloaded SharePoint Designer 2013.  I am getting a 403 forbidden when trying to open a site from the new computer but when trying to access the sites from my old computer with an SharePoint Designer 2013, I am granted access.  In the new download on the new computer, my account is set to the same account as the old instance.  I am a global admin.  Our sites are classic sites right now until we develop in modern team sites and communications sites, so that is not the issue.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the account have enough permissions to the sites.

According to this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-admin-role

Global admins and SharePoint admins don't have automatic access to all sites and each user's OneDrive, but they can give themselves access to any site or OneDrive.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I am a site owner as well as site admin and Global admin.  The issue is that from my old computer with SharePoint Designer, I can access the sites.  On my new computer where I downloaded the latest SharePoint Designer 2013, I am getting the 403 error.  I am using the same login.  I looked for a Service Pack for SP Designer 2013 but I am up to date.

Comment: Is there any policy in your tenant which block access for unmanaged devices?

Comment: I apologize for the delay.  No, there are no policies that block unmanaged devices.